# Swift Firebase TableView distance from current user

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, location, distance

I am trying to list the distance in a label from the current user to the business location. I keep on getting a error saying `"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value"` and I am getting this error on a firebase line, yet I know for a fact I have everything spelled correctly and the call works to get the values. I get the error on line:
`"let lat = Double(locationValue["businessLatitude"] as! String)"`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! RegisteredLocationsCell
    let user : NSDictionary?

    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != ""{

        user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]

        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Businesses").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            if let locationData = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
                let locationValue = locationData as! [String: Any]

                let lat = Double(locationValue["businessLatitude"] as! String)
                let long = Double(locationValue["businessLongitude"] as! String)
                let businessLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat!, longitude: long!)

                let latitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude
                let longitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude
                let userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)

                let distanceInMeters : Double = userLocation.distance(from: businessLocation)
                let distanceInMiles : Double = ((distanceInMeters.description as String).doubleValue * 0.00062137)
                cell.businessDistance.text = "\(distanceInMiles.string(2)) miles away"
            }
        })

    } else {

        user = self.usersArray[indexPath.row]

        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Businesses").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            if let locationData = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
            let locationValue = locationData as! [String: Any]

            let lat = Double(locationValue["businessLatitude"] as! String)
            let long = Double(locationValue["businessLongitude"] as! String)
            let businessLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat!, longitude: long!)

            let latitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude
            let longitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude
            let userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)

            let distanceInMeters : Double = userLocation.distance(from: businessLocation)
            let distanceInMiles : Double = ((distanceInMeters.description as String).doubleValue * 0.00062137)
            cell.businessDistance.text = "\(distanceInMiles.string(2)) miles away"
            }

        })
    }

    cell.businessName.text = String(user?["businessName"] as! String)
    cell.businessStreet.text = String(user?["businessStreet"] as! String)
    cell.businessCity.text = String(user?["businessCity"] as! String)
    cell.businessState.text = String(user?["businessState"] as! String)

    //cell.configure(businessName: user?["businessName"] as! String, businessStreet: user?["businessStreet"] as! String, businessCity: user?["businessCity"] as! String, businessState: user?["businessState"] as! String, businessDistance: user?["businessDistance"] as! String )

    return cell
}
```

[image: Added "print(locationValue)"]

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class RegisteredLocationsTableView: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, CLLocationManagerDelegate, NSUserActivityDelegate {

@IBOutlet var followUsersTableView: UITableView!
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

var loggedInUser:FIRUser?
var loggedInUserData:NSDictionary?
var usersArray = [NSDictionary?]()
var filteredUsers = [NSDictionary?]()

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
let distanceFormatter = MKDistanceFormatter()
var locationData: NSDictionary?
var geofences = [CLCircularRegion]()
var nameKeyDict:[String:String] = [:]


var databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()


    databaseRef.child("Businesses").queryOrdered(byChild: "businessName").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        let key = snapshot.key
        let snapshot = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        snapshot?.setValue(key, forKey: "uid")

        if(key == self.loggedInUser?.uid) {
            print("Same as logged in user, so don't show!")
        } else {
            self.usersArray.append(snapshot)

            //insert the rows
            self.followUsersTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:self.usersArray.count-1,section:0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
        }

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != ""{
        return filteredUsers.count
    }
    return self.usersArray.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! RegisteredLocationsCell
    let user : NSDictionary?

    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != ""{

        user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]

        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Businesses").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
            if let locationValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {


                let lat = Double(locationValue["businessLatitude"] as! String)
                let long = Double(locationValue["businessLongitude"] as! String)
                let businessLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat!, longitude: long!)

                let latitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude
                let longitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude
                let userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)

                let distanceInMeters : Double = userLocation.distance(from: businessLocation)
                let distanceInMiles : Double = ((distanceInMeters.description as String).doubleValue * 0.00062137)
                cell.businessDistance.text = "\(distanceInMiles.string(2)) miles away"
            }
        })

    } else {

        user = self.usersArray[indexPath.row]

        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Businesses").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
            if let locationValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {


                let lat = Double(locationValue["businessLatitude"] as! String)
                let long = Double(locationValue["businessLongitude"] as! String)
                let businessLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat!, longitude: long!)

                let latitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude
                let longitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude
                let userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)

                let distanceInMeters : Double = userLocation.distance(from: businessLocation)
                let distanceInMiles : Double = ((distanceInMeters.description as String).doubleValue * 0.00062137)
                cell.businessDistance.text = "\(distanceInMiles.string(2)) miles away"
            }
        })
    }

    cell.businessName.text = String(user?["businessName"] as! String)
    cell.businessStreet.text = String(user?["businessStreet"] as! String)
    cell.businessCity.text = String(user?["businessCity"] as! String)
    cell.businessState.text = String(user?["businessState"] as! String)


    //cell.configure(businessName: user?["businessName"] as! String, businessStreet: user?["businessStreet"] as! String, businessCity: user?["businessCity"] as! String, businessState: user?["businessState"] as! String, businessDistance: user?["businessDistance"] as! String )

    return cell
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
    if segue.identifier == "BusinessProfiles" {
        // gotta check if we're currently searching
        if self.searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]
                let controller = segue.destination as? BusinessProfilesViewController
                controller?.otherUser = user
            }
        } else {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let user = usersArray[indexPath.row]
                let controller = segue.destination as? BusinessProfilesViewController
                controller?.otherUser = user
            }
        }
    }
}


func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    filterContent(searchText: self.searchController.searchBar.text!)
}

func filterContent(searchText:String) {
    self.filteredUsers = self.usersArray.filter { user in

        let username = user!["businessName"] as? String

        return(username?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))!
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}

}
```

Comment: Please add print(locationValue) before this error line and see what it prints?

Comment: user1000 I just added the picture

Comment: Ok please add this print(locationValue["businessLatitude"]) after above print and see what it prints? and please tell me the output

Comment: it comes as nil

Comment: if you replace let locationValue = locationData as! [String: Any] with let locationValue = locationData as! [[String: Any]] and then add let singleDictionary = locationValue[0] and then add print(singleDictionary) , see what it prints

Comment: That created errors. "let locationValue = locationData as! [[String:Any]]" - Always fails. And where I have my firebase calls it says "Cannot subscript value of type [[String:Any]] with an index of type 'String"

Comment: Please check my answer,see if it helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add .childAdded as observe eventtype
Try this:

```
 FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Businesses").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
                if let locationValue = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {


                    let lat = Double(locationValue["businessLatitude"] as! String)
                    let long = Double(locationValue["businessLongitude"] as! String)
                    let businessLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat!, longitude: long!)

                    let latitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude
                    let longitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude
                    let userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)

                    let distanceInMeters : Double = userLocation.distance(from: businessLocation)
                    let distanceInMiles : Double = ((distanceInMeters.description as String).doubleValue * 0.00062137)
                    cell.businessDistance.text = "\(distanceInMiles.string(2)) miles away"
                }
            })
```

Update:

You need to remove the `FIRDatabse` calls from `cellForRowAt` method and modify your call in `viewDidLoad` as follows:

```
databaseRef.child("Businesses").queryOrdered(byChild: "businessName").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        let key = snapshot.key


        if(key == self.loggedInUser?.uid) {
            print("Same as logged in user, so don't show!")
        } else {
            if let locationValue = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
             let lat = Double(locationValue["businessLatitude"] as! String)
                    let long = Double(locationValue["businessLongitude"] as! String)
                    let businessLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat!, longitude: long!)

                    let latitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude
                    let longitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude
                    let userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)

                    let distanceInMeters : Double = userLocation.distance(from: businessLocation)
                    let distanceInMiles : Double = ((distanceInMeters.description as String).doubleValue * 0.00062137)
             let distanceLabelText = "\(distanceInMiles.string(2)) miles away"

             var singleChildDictionary = locationValue
             singleChildDictionary["distanceLabelText"] = distanceLabelText
             self.usersArray.append(singleChildDictionary)

}


            //insert the rows
            self.followUsersTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:self.usersArray.count-1,section:0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
        }

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Then in cellForRowAt method

add this at the end like you are assigning other values

```
cell.businessDistance.text = String(user?["distanceLabelText"] as! String)
```

Comment: for some reason on snapshot it brings up a error saying "Ambiguous reference to member value"

Comment: @LukasBimba ok let me see

Comment: Need a picture or something? Or you going to test it??

Comment: @LukasBimba Can you please tell me that error occurs at this line if let locationValue = snapshot.value as? Dictionary ? or somewhere else?

Comment: Nevermind I rewrote it and it compiled fine. Now only problem is it shows the same distance for all locations

Comment: yeah, thanks. If you can't help further, no worries.

Comment: @LukasBimba glad I could help, and you are getting the same distance because as can be seen in image your latitude and longitude values are same for all dictionaries, hope it help, they only differ by 0.000003 approx

Comment: Sorry but I just added another location further away and still shows same distance. I am sure it's because I am setting the label inside the firebase call instead of the "CellForRow" where each locations details would be set

Comment: @LukasBimba Are you using search delegate methods?

Comment: I'll add my whole view controller

Comment: For "distanceLabelText" xcode wants me to add "distanceLabelText as AnyObject" and for "(singleChildDictionary)" it wants me to add "(singleChildDictionary as NSDictionary)"

Comment: I ran it works fine. Thank You. Also, how would you recommend I sort these places from closest to furthest? "func sortMapItems()  {
        self.mapItems = self.mapItems.sorted(by: { (b, a) -> Bool in
            return self.userLocation.location!.distance(from: a.placemark.location!) > self.userLocation.location!.distance(from: b.placemark.location!)
        })
    } " I've used this piece of code for mkmapitems but not sure if it would be the same for here

Comment: @LukasBimba Please ask a separate question, as this is totally a different question, I will try to help you there, hope you understand, thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45866712/swift-firebase-sort-by-distance  Here is the question