# Swift Firebase Sort By Distance

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, tableview

I am trying to sort my array by distance. I already have everything hooked up to grab the distance's but unsure how to sort from closest to furthest from the users location. I've used the below code for MKMapItem's yet unsure how to apply to my current array.

```
func sortMapItems()  {
                    self.mapItems = self.mapItems.sorted(by: { (b, a) -> Bool in
                        return self.userLocation.location!.distance(from: a.placemark.location!) > self.userLocation.location!.distance(from: b.placemark.location!)
                    })
                }
```

**Firebase Call**

```
databaseRef.child("Businesses").queryOrdered(byChild: "businessName").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        let key = snapshot.key

        if(key == self.loggedInUser?.uid) {
            print("Same as logged in user, so don't show!")
        } else {
            if let locationValue = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let lat = Double(locationValue["businessLatitude"] as! String)
                let long = Double(locationValue["businessLongitude"] as! String)
                let businessLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat!, longitude: long!)

                let latitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude
                let longitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude
                let userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)

                let distanceInMeters : Double = userLocation.distance(from: businessLocation)
                let distanceInMiles : Double = ((distanceInMeters.description as String).doubleValue * 0.00062137)
                let distanceLabelText = "\(distanceInMiles.string(2)) miles away"

                var singleChildDictionary = locationValue
                singleChildDictionary["distanceLabelText"] = distanceLabelText as AnyObject
                self.usersArray.append(singleChildDictionary as NSDictionary)

                /*
                func sortMapItems()  {
                    self.mapItems = self.mapItems.sorted(by: { (b, a) -> Bool in
                        return self.userLocation.location!.distance(from: a.placemark.location!) > self.userLocation.location!.distance(from: b.placemark.location!)
                    })
                }
                */

            }


            //insert the rows
            self.followUsersTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:self.usersArray.count-1,section:0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
        }

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to sort the usersArray according to distanceLabelText?

Comment: Yes that would be perfect

Comment: Where do you want to sort the usersArray and why?

Comment: I am guessing within the firebase call because the sort needs access to the array. Or maybe how it was done before by just calling a function? Not sure what would be most efficient

Comment: I can access the userLocation but trying to get access to the usersArray is the problem

Comment: "self.usersArray = self.usersArray.sorted(by: { (b, a) -> Bool in
                            return userLocation.distance(from: a) > userLocation.distance(from: b.placemark.location!)
                        })" tried working on it like this

Comment: Check my answer see if it helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make these changes in your code

```
singleChildDictionary["distanceInMiles"] = distanceInMiles
```

Then you can sort it like this:

```
self.usersArray = self.usersArray.sorted {
        !($0["distanceInMiles"] as! Double > $1["distanceInMiles"] as! Double)
}
```

Comment: Where would I declare this? Within the call?

Comment: I am guessing the second part could be a function and could be put anywhere in the file?

Comment: @LukasBimba add first line after singleChildDictionary["distanceLabelText"] = distanceLabelText as AnyObject and then add the second part after self.usersArray.append(singleChildDictionary as NSDictionary)

Comment: xcode wants me to remove "sorted", like how it does when its being unused. Throws a warning

Comment: I guess just leave it be?

Comment: @LukasBimba glad I could help

Comment: 1 problem. My tableview now shows two of the same places

Comment: @LukasBimba please explain , what do you mean by that?

Comment: The data is correct that it passes but whats displayed on the label shows duplicates

Comment: @LukasBimba for example?

Comment: So I have 4 places in my database. The first place in the tableview is correct, the next two are duplicates, and the last place is correct

Comment: The second place labels show the third place labels, so the second place is incorrect

Comment: var singleChildDictionary = locationValue
                    singleChildDictionary["distanceLabelText"] = distanceLabelText as AnyObject
                    singleChildDictionary["distanceInMiles"] = distanceInMiles as AnyObject
                    self.usersArray.append(singleChildDictionary as NSDictionary)
                    self.usersArray = self.usersArray.sorted {
                        !($0?["distanceInMiles"] as! Double > $1?["distanceInMiles"] as! Double)
                    }

Comment: @LukasBimba if you replace self.followUsersTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:self.usersArray.count-1,section:0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic) by self.followUsersTableView.reloadData() , then what is the result? please check

Comment: Wow that weird. Once I selected the search bar, it transitioned into the correct place. really weird

Comment: Havent tried your new comment but yeah, once I select the search bar the labels become correct

Comment: @LukasBimba the reason is that when you select the search bar , filterContent() method is called where you are reloading the tableview

Comment: xcode throws a error after "UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic" saying to add a ";" at the end of it

Comment: @LukasBimba you added this line self.followUsersTableView.reloadData() instead of self.followUsersTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:self.usersArray.count-1,section:0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic) ?

Comment: Sorry I got confused lol, just replaced it and now its perfect. Thank you very much man great work